# Loop an array of objects and get a new object based on comparing objects values

Tags: javascript, arrays, javascript-objects

I have this array in my state:

```js
[
  {
    id: "17CVqaiM",
    styles: {
      desktop: {
        height: 163,
        width: 163,
        left: 498,
        top: 350
      },
      mobile: {
        height: 150,
        width: 150,
        left: 135,
        top: 205
      }
    }
  },
  {
    id: "xL-4vIfV",
    styles: {
      desktop: {
        height: 150,
        width: 150,
        left: 675,
        top: 91
      },
      mobile: {
        height: 150,
        width: 150,
        left: 105,
        top: 175
      }
    }
  }
];
```

How can i loop through it and based on styles key and device type (desktop or mobile), compare their values and then get an object with these properties?

```js
{
  [desktop || mobile]: {
    // the formula for desktop or mobile is the same. only the styles objects is different
    top: "least top value in desktop styles objects",
    left: "least left value in desktop styles objects",
    width: "(most left value in desktop styles objects + that object width) - least left value in desktop styles objects",
    height: "(most top value in desktop styles objects + that object height) - least top value in desktop styles objects"
  }
}
```

I tried using this reduce function but can't figure it out properly.

```js
array.reduce((prev, current) => {
  const top = {
    prev: prev.styles[device].top,
    current: current.styles[device].top
  };
  const left = {
    prev: prev.styles[device].left,
    current: current.styles[device].left
  };
  const width = {
    prev: prev.styles[device].width,
    current: current.styles[device].width
  };
  const height = {
    prev: prev.styles[device].height,
    current: current.styles[device].height
  };

  return {
    [device]: {
      top: (top.prev < top.current ? top.prev : top.current) + "px",
      left: (left.prev < left.current ? left.prev : left.current) + "px",
      width: (left.prev > left.current
          ? left.prev + width.prev - left.current
          : left.current + width.current - left.prev) + "px",
      height: (top.prev > top.current
          ? top.prev + height.prev
          : top.current + height.current) -
        (top.prev < top.current ? top.prev : top.current) + "px"
    }
  };
});
```

This only works for 2 items in the array and not more.

Comment: Please post your reduce function - Also it's not exactly cleat about the expected result values... What means exactly *most/least* and what it refers to?!

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan I updated the question.

Comment: @AliMoghadami if you run this code, what is your `device`?

Comment: @Danny `device` is a react component prop, the value of it is either 'desktop' or 'mobile'.

Comment: @Danny I forgot about the device. the question is updated

Comment: I think you got mess with `reduce`, the `prev` aka `accumulator` is the result when it loops  before the `cur` element.

Answer (score 0):

Don't concat `px` when you return in `reduce`, you can compare exactly.
Try this:

```
const result = array.reduce((acc, cur) => {
  const top = {
    acc: acc[device].top,
    cur: current.styles[device].top,
  }
  // ...
  return {
    [device]: {
      top: top.acc < top.cur ? top.acc : top.cur,
      // ...
    }
  }
}, {
  [device]: {
    top: 0,
    left: 0,
    width: 0,
    height: 0,
  }
})

array[device].top += 'px'
// ...
```

Answer (score 0):

## Question

compare two objects based on `styles` key and `device type` (e.g. mobile, or desktop)

## Your Code

```
const compareObj = ((prev, current) => {
  const top = {
      prev: prev.styles[device].top,
      current: current.styles[device].top,
  };
  const left = {
      prev: prev.styles[device].left,
      current: current.styles[device].left,
  };
  const width = {
      prev: prev.styles[device].width,
      current: current.styles[device].width,
  };
  const height = {
      prev: prev.styles[device].height,
      current: current.styles[device].height,
  };

  return {
      top: (top.prev < top.current ? top.prev : top.current) + 'px',
      left: (left.prev < left.current ? left.prev : left.current) + 'px',
      width: (left.prev > left.current
              ? left.prev + width.prev - left.current
              : left.current + width.current - left.prev) + 'px',
      height: (top.prev > top.current
              ? top.prev + height.prev
              : top.current + height.current) -
          (top.prev < top.current ? top.prev : top.current) + 'px',
  };
});

const dummies = [
  {
    id: "17CVqaiM",
    styles: {
      desktop: {
        height: 163,
        width: 163,
        left: 498,
        top: 350
      },
      mobile: {
        height: 150,
        width: 150,
        left: 135,
        top: 205
      }
    }
  },
  {
    id: "xL-4vIfV",
    styles: {
      desktop: {
        height: 150,
        width: 150,
        left: 675,
        top: 91
      },
      mobile: {
        height: 150,
        width: 150,
        left: 105,
        top: 175
      }
    }
  }
];

console.log(compareObj(dummies[0], dummies[1]));
```

## Your Code's Result

```
prev: prev.styles[device].top,
                        ^
ReferenceError: device is not defined
```

## Reason for your code's result

You called your `device` key from `styles` object, but it is  undefined value.

## Solution

You need to check the variable(or key) you called is exist.

## My code is

```
// the dummy data you will use
const dummies = [
  {
    id: "17CVqaiM",
    styles: {
      desktop: {
        height: 163,
        width: 163,
        left: 498,
        top: 350
      },
      mobile: {
        height: 150,
        width: 150,
        left: 135,
        top: 205
      }
    }
  },
  {
    id: "xL-4vIfV",
    styles: {
      desktop: {
        height: 150,
        width: 150,
        left: 675,
        top: 91
      },
      mobile: {
        height: 150,
        width: 150,
        left: 105,
        top: 175
      }
    }
  }
];

// function for comparing the style by device type
const compareStyles = (prev, current, deviceType) => {
  const prevDeviceStyle = prev.styles[deviceType];
  const currentDeviceStyle = current.styles[deviceType];

  // set variable combinedStyleObject for return 
  const combinedStyleObject = {};

  // compare prev and current style object with using for-in loop
  for (const eachProperty in prevDeviceStyle) {
    if (prevDeviceStyle[eachProperty] < currentDeviceStyle[eachProperty]) {
      combinedStyleObject[eachProperty] = `${prevDeviceStyle[eachProperty]}px`;
      continue;
    }
    combinedStyleObject[eachProperty] = `${currentDeviceStyle[eachProperty]}px`;
  }

  // return combinedStyleObject
  return combinedStyleObject;
};

// An array for your device type, to handle the case when you want to compare more device type.
// if you want to add more type such as 'tablet', just put it in this deviceTypes array!
const deviceTypes = ['mobile', 'desktop'];

// compare and reduce your style objects by device type!
const reducedStyles = deviceTypes.map(eachType => {
  return compareStyles(...dummies, eachType);
});

// check the result
console.log(JSON.stringify(reducedStyles));
```

## Output

```
[
  { "height":"150px", "width":"150px", "left":"105px", "top":"175px" },
  { "height":"150px", "width":"150px", "left":"498px", "top":"91px" },
];
```

hope my answer might help your problem!